# Wordpress - Exclude posts from author from wp_query

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to exclude posts by the author with the ID "1" form WP_Query. This still shows all posts by all users.

Any thoughts?

```
<?php
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query( array( 'author' => -1 ) );
$wp_query->query('posts_per_page=35'.'&paged='.$paged);
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
?>
    <div class="grid__third">
        ...
    </div>
<?php endwhile; // end of loop
?>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try : `$wp_query = new WP_Query( array( 'author__not_in' => array( 1 ) ) );`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
global $post;
$args=array('author' => '-1', //excludes users with id 1.
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => 12,
'ignore_sticky_posts'=> 1,);
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
<li>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</li>
<?php endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

or

```
// The Query
$args=array('author' => '-1', //excludes users with id 1.
'post_type' => 'post','post_status' => 'publish','posts_per_page' => 12,'ignore_sticky_posts'=> 1,);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); // The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
echo '<ul>';
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();}else {
// no posts found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your query is not working with

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query( array( 'author' => -1 ) );
```

then, You can try some other logic. Like inside the loop get the ID of the author by using POST ID:

```
$post_author_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_id ); // You will get your author id here
```

Then apply condition like `if($post_author_id != 1){ // YOUR POST }` This will display post of all author except author with ID = 1.

Full code like:

```
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
$post_author_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', HERE YOUR POST ID );
if($post_author_id != 1){
?>
    <div class="grid__third">
        ...
    </div>
<?php
} endwhile; // end of loop
```

Hope this will helpful for you. Thanks.